# How do I loop this function so that it keeps asking for the option rather than exiting the entire program every time I complete an option's task?

Tags: python, function, class, printing, parameters

To give you some background info, I basically have to create 2 classes called ItemToPurchase that contains an item's name, quantity, description, and price. The other class ShoppingCart adds the item's name into a list with some other functions that modify the list. The part where I am facing some issues is at the part of execute_menu(). Let's say I enter the option 'a', after I give all the details of the item, the entire program ends. I do not want that. I want the program to ask me for the next option and keep asking me the next option after I complete a specific letter's required details.

```
class ItemToPurchase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'none'
        self.quantity = 0
        self.price = 0
        self.description = 'none'

    def item_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def item_price(self, price):
        self.price = price

    def item_quantity(self, quantity):
        self.quantity = quantity

    def item_description(self, description):
        self.description = description

    def print_item_cost(self):
        print(self.name + " " + str(self.quantity) + " @ $" + str(self.price) + " = $" + str(int(self.quantity) * int(self.price)))

    def print_item_description(self):
        print(self.name + ": " + self.description)

class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self, name='none', date='January 1, 2016'):
        self.customer_name = name
        self.current_date = date
        self.cart_items = []

    def add_item(self, New_cart):
        self.cart_items.append(New_cart)

    def remove_item(self, item_name):
        count = 0
        items = self.cart_items[:]
        for i in range(len(items)):
            item = items[i]
            if item.name == item_name:
                del self.cart_items[i]
                count += 1
        if count == 0:
            print()
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing removed')
            
    def modify_item(self, ItemToPurchase, Item_Name):
        num = 0
        items = self.cart_items[:]
        for i in range(len(items)):
            item = items[i]
            if Item_Name in [x.name for x in items]:
                num += 1
                if ItemToPurchase.description != "none":
                    item.item_description(ItemToPurchase.description)
                if ItemToPurchase.price != 0:
                    item.item_price(ItemToPurchase.price)
                if ItemToPurchase.quantity != 0:
                    item.item_quantity(ItemToPurchase.quantity)

        if num == 0:
            print()
            print('Item not found in cart. Nothing modified.')
            print()
        
            

    def get_num_items_in_cart(self):
        total_number = 0
        items = self.cart_items[:]
        for i in range(len(items)):
            item = items[i]
            total_number += item.quantity
        return total_number

    def get_cost_of_cart(self):
        total_cost = 0
        items = self.cart_items[:]
        for i in range(len(items)):
            item = items[i]
            total_cost += int(item.quantity*item.price)
        return total_cost
                       

    def print_total(self):
        print(self.customer_name + "'s Shopping Cart - " + str(self.current_date))
        count = len(self.cart_items) + 1
        if len(self.cart_items) > 0:
            print('Number of items:' + str(count))
            print()
            for i in self.cart_items:
                i.print_item_cost()
            total = self.get_cost_of_cart()
            print()
            print('Total:', str(total))
        else:
            print('SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY')

    def print_descriptions(self):
        if len(self.cart_items) > 0:
            print(self.customer_name + "'s Shopping Cart - " + str(self.current_date))
            print()
            print('Item Descriptions')
            for j in self.cart_items:
                j.print_item_description()
        else:
            print('SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY')
        

def print_menu(cart):
    print('MENU')
    print('a - Add item to cart')
    print('r - Remove item from cart')
    print('c - Change item quantity')
    print("i - Output items' descriptions")
    print('o - Output shopping cart')
    print('q - Quit')

**def execute_menu(option, Cart):
    while option != 'q':
        if option == 'o':
            print('OUTPUT SHOPPING CART')
            Cart.print_total()
            break
        elif option == 'i':
            print("OUTPUT ITEMS' DESCRIPTIONS")
            Cart.print_descriptions()
            break
        elif option == 'a':
            print('ADD ITEM TO CART')
            print('Enter the item name:')
            itemName = input()
            print('Enter the item description:')
            itemDescrip = input()
            print('Enter the item price:')
            itemPrice = int(input())
            print('Enter the item quantity:')
            itemQuan = int(input())
            New_cart = ItemToPurchase()
            New_cart.name = itemName
            New_cart.quantity = itemQuan
            New_cart.price = itemPrice
            New_cart.description = itemDescrip
            Cart.add_item(New_cart)
            break
        elif option == 'r':
            print('REMOVE ITEM FROM CART')
            print('Enter name of item to remove:')
            ItemName = input()
            Cart.remove_item(ItemName)
            break
        elif option == 'c':
            print('CHANGE ITEM QUANTITY:')
            print('Enter the item name:')
            Item_Name = input()
            print('Enter the new quantity:')
            Item_Quantity = int(input())
            item_s = ItemToPurchase()
            item_s.item_quantity(Item_Quantity)
            Cart.modify_item(item_s, Item_Name)
            break**
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Enter customer's name:")
    customer = input()
    print("Enter today's date:")
    date = input()
    print()
    print('Customer name:', customer)
    print("Today's date:", date)
    Cart = ShoppingCart(customer, date)
    option = ''
    print()
    print_menu(Cart)
    print()
    print('Choose an option:')
    option = input().lower().strip()
    execute_menu(option, Cart)
```

The reason why I am adding the break is cause the program keeps printing the end print item infinit amount of times if I do not add the break.
Any help is appreciated. thank you and have a great day ahead!

Comment: I basically want the program to print the menu again and then ask me for my option.

Comment: The while-loop in "execute_menu" doesn't end because "option" isn't modified in the loop. Therefore it can't become "q". Better wrap the part of code on module level you want to repeat in a "while True:" loop (including the code to receive an option from user) and if option is "q" break the loop.

Comment: You need to put your "choose an option" input at the top of your loop (and remove it from your main code).  Without it, it will just keep using the same input over and over again, just as you've seen.  You should try to learn to debug something simple like this on your own.